# How to reduce table size at pdf rendered from html by jSPDF?

Tags: javascript, jspdf

There is a table at my html page. I have used `jSPDF` to convert that html view into PDF. It takes two pages in PDF. So, table header (`thead`) is showing at both of the pages. I don't want header in second page. So, I think if I could reduce table size (with column line height etc.), it would fit in one page so that there will be only one `thead`. Also, there will be maximum 12 rows in that table always. That's why, I want to fit the view in one page in the PDF. How to do that?

[Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/learner73/cpuLrnxx/17/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I faced a similar issue. Changing the line : `var doc = new jsPDF();` to 
`var doc = new jsPDF('portrait', 'pt', 'a4');` solves the problem. The table now fits in a single page [as shown here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZWZvT.png)